# Netbean Cannot update Google App Engine server to appengine-java-sdk-1.3.2

Tags: google-app-engine, netbeans6.7

I am using Netbean 6.7.1

I just update my google app engine plugin in netbean with Netbean auto update. I found out there is new app engine SDK. So i want to update my google app engine server to point to appengine-java-sdk-1.3.2

After I download appengine-java-sdk-1.3.2.zip. I unzip it. Then at Netbean:

I already have a Google App Engine server under Services -> Server. I can't find anyway to point it to the newly installed sdk folder. So I deleted the existing "Google App Engine" server & try to add a new one.

Server -> Add Server -> Google App Engine ->

at "Installation Location", I point it to google app engine folder, which is
"C:\appengine-java-sdk-1.3.2", it show this message at bottom "C:\appengine-java-sdk-1.3.2" & don't allow me to continue.

May I know how to solve this? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have sorted it out already. This is because when I extract / unzip the sdk zip file, it create 2 levels of same directory for the unzip files. Thus I should choose the "Installation Location" to be "C:\appengine-java-sdk-1.3.2\appengine-java-sdk-1.3.2\".

Thanks anyway!

Comment: well, thanks for asking the question.  In my case: D:\Work\Downloads\appengine-java-sdk-1.3.8\appengine-java-sdk-1.3.8   that's gotta be the stupidest thing ever.  Who puts one directory in another with the same name?  Ohhh, I bet it's just how Windows extracts zip files, betcha that it's different for Mac/Linux.  doh!